# Is it possible to backup and emulate an USB stick, e.g. including its serial number and other hardware specs?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, hardware-virtualization

I have a notsocheap software here sitting on a really cheap usb stick and I don't really trust this stick especially because it's in every days use an many changing machines. The software on the stick is in two versions for OS X and for Win, the stick is formated in FAt32.
The software itself is "portable" and runs directly from the stick or from anywhere but uses the stick as a kind of dongle; maybe the serial number or the vendor is checked, I have no clue.

Is it possible to make a kind of "usb stick vm" where everything from the original hardware is kept so there is no need to get the cheapo stick around all day? This would be great!

Comment: Might want to try copying it with DD, then DD it into another disk of the same size, to see if it works

Comment: @Journeyman Geek: I tried dd but this only does a sector copy of the file system.
But in this case the vendor seems to use some kind of hardware information from exactly THIS stick to generate the license file (which also sits on the stick).
Every backup I tested failed because on the new medium the license file is not accepted. That's why I think some kind of hardware virtualisation may be needed.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It can't hurt trying. Just NEVER insert the real stick and the clone into the same computer at the same time after the clone is made. It could REALLY create problems.

Comment: @X-File If it uses any sort of hardware identifier associated with the chip on the stick you're in trouble. You best check the contract you have with the vendor if they will replace the stick free of charge or small fee when it breaks, because sooner or later it will break. In any case: Make a copy of the software on the computers that need to run it and use the stick ONLY as license dongle. That would greatly reduce the changes of the stick breaking.

Comment: @Tonny: The vendor is out of business what makes it even more necessary to not wait until this stick dies :-P

Comment: @X-File I've been in your situation a couple of years ago. Eventually the USB-storage on the stick went bad, but the license-dongle functionality kept working. In fact still does until today. Stick is about 18 years old now.

Comment: @X-File Did your try a DD of the whole disk instead of the filesystem? Sometimes they hide the license key in extra disk-sectors outside the filesystem. A full-disk DD should copy those too. But that would usually imply the program would need to be run with admin-rights all the time (or there is a special driver or service installed on each computer on first run, which requires one-time admin-rights for the 1st run).

Answer (score 0):

It is easy enough to copy a disk sector-by-sector.

On Linux you can use the `dd` command, and on Windows a utility such as
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/download.html).

If by "serial number" you mean the disk label, this is easy to set.
In Windows you would use Explorer, right-click the disk, select Properties,
and set the label in the General tab.

However, the vendor of the software might have used any number of protection
schemes which a sector-by-sector copy will not duplicate correctly.
If the key employs such a scheme then the above will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a backup of the USB stick as an ISO file. This is possible using applications such as ImgBurn. 
[Convert USB to ISO](https://aatayyab.wordpress.com/2016/05/09/convert-bootable-usb-to-an-iso-image/)
Said ISO file can then be loaded virtually using windows explorer, or loaded on another USB flash drive.

I highly doubt the application uses the USB serial number. This is impractical on a large scale usually. I'd create an ISO, burn it to another USB stick and check the program for functionality.